# How to access SQLite database?

Tags: sql-server, sql, sqlite

I have run BinDiff on two binary files, and stored the results in a .BinDiff file. (Which the manufactures assure me is just an SQLite database. How would I open and access this database?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. Normally, you should be using the tools that BinDiff provides. If you want to examine the information manually, then you can use any SQLite program like the [default SQLite tools](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html#win32), or a [third-party viewer](http://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite+viewer).

Comment: You can even use the [SQLite firefox extension](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/)!

Comment: Thank you, I am now just having trouble with the data moving from one application to another. I think this may be a problem with my BinDiff.

Comment: Is there a way to view it via linux terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft Access to do this ([Look here](http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqliteodbc.htm)) or use a SQLite Database Browser (For example [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)). As @Synetech said you can of curse use the standard tools to access the database too.